# Lambert W function equation

Tags: linear-algebra, lambert-w

I was attempting to solve different types of equations using the Lambert W function. I stumbled across one that depending on how the signs were placed I was able to solve it or not. For instance, I’ve had no problem solving $e^{-2x} + 1 = 3x$, however, solving $e^{-2x} - 1 = -3x$ has been somewhat imposible. I’ve tried all types of substitutions and transformations albeit nothing seems to work. If someone could guide me on how to solve the equation that will really help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on [Wolfram's results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+in+e%5E(-2x)+-1+%3D+-3x) you'll have to use the analytic continuation of the W function to complex numbers, seems like. I'm not sure how that would change the overall nature of the problem, though, I'm a bit of a novice at using it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $e^{2x}$ both sides gives
$$1-e^{2x}=-3xe^{2x}$$
$$e^{2x}(3x-1)=-1$$
$$e^{2x}(2x-\frac23)=-\frac23$$
$$e^{2x-\frac23}(2x-\frac23)=-\frac23 e^{-\frac23}$$
$$2x-\frac23=W_n(-\frac23 e^{-\frac23})\,\,\, n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x=\frac13+\frac12W_n(-\frac23 e^{-\frac23})\,\,\, n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
There are infinite values of the Lambert-W function and in this case there are two real valued solutions - the principal value of the Lambert-W function $W_0(-\frac23 e^{-\frac23})=-\frac23$ and the value $W_{-1}(-\frac23 e^{-\frac23})\approx-1.429355228 $

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm aware that one of the two real solutions is x=0, I've in fact already tried your approach, though I'm more interested in finding a way to solve for the other real solution which is in the form of the Lamber W function.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the solution. There are in fact infinite solutions, but the two real solutions are given by the branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: I thought that $W_{-1}$ would also equal $\frac{2}{3}$ since it is in the form $xe^x$, but that only happens in $W_{0}$. Thanks for addressing this!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old. Wanted to answer it anyway. My solution:

```
       e^(-2x) - 1    =          -3x
       
       e^(-2x)        =          -3x + 1
```

e^(+2x) e^(-2x)        =         (-3x + 1)   e^(+2x)

```
       e^(0)          =         (-3x + 1)   e^(+2x)

 [-2/3]    1          =  [-2/3] (-3x + 1)   e^(+2x)

 [-2/3]    1          =         (2x  -2/3)  e^(+2x)
```

[-2/3]      * e^(-2/3)   =     (2x  -2/3)  e^(+2x) * e^(-2/3)

```
   [-2/3]* e^(-2/3)   =     (2x  -2/3)  e^(+2x - 2/3)      Lambert Form:
```

exponent argument same as non-exponent argument.

W[ (-2/3) * e^(-2/3)]  =   W [(2x  -2/3) e^(+2x - 2/3)]

W [(0.34226)]          =      (2x  -2/3)

From Wolfram Alpha: W0 = productlog (0, -0.34226) = -0.666561  main branch

```
              W(-1)= productlog (-1, -0.34226) = -1.42953 Secondary branch.
```

Check:  Main branch:  -0.666561 = 2x - 0.666   (x = 0)  : e^0 - 1 = -3(0): 1-1 = 0

```
    Secondary branch -1.42953 = 2x - 0.666  (x = -0.381765)

    e^(-2(-0.381765) - 1 = -3 *(-0.381765)               
        
        2.1468       - 1 =  1.144

        1.468          approx. 1.44
```

Sorry no math editor. Answer not as good as some of the experts up here but looks correct.